# invalid object when added to policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add this effect to my policy using YAML

```
Policies:
    - PolicyName: !Sub 'X-${AWS::Region}'
      PolicyDocument:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 'ssm:GetParametersByPath'
          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/X'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 'ssm:GetParameters'
          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/X/*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 's3:*'
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
          Resource:
            - !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:C*'

        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
            - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
            - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
            - 'ec2:DescribeInstances'
            - 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface'
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 'kms:Decrypt'
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow #added this effect
          Action: sqs:*
          Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:Q.fifo

    RoleName: !Sub 'X-${AWS::Region}'
```

when I run it I get

> Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object

what I added / what I can take away and it works

```
 - Effect: Allow #added this effect
          Action: sqs:*
          Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:Q.fifo
```

**Clearly I did not include the account number**

Anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix

Comment: What is the FULL definition of the policy or role?

Comment: added full policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [missing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#aws-resource-iam-policy--examples) `Version` and `Statement` in your `PolicyDocument`. All your `Effect` objects should be under `Statement`:

```
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'ssm:GetParametersByPath'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/X'
          - and the rest
```

Comment: Have to say I didn't think this would make a lick of difference. Thank you